# Newbe trying to serialize objects with protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

I have two simple classes which I want to serialize with protobuf-net. Everything looks OK but when I deserialize the Body property is null. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace Protobuf_test
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var innerObject = new Inner() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
            var outerObject = new Outer() { Body = innerObject };

            using (var stream = File.Create("serialized.bin"))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, outerObject);
            }
            using (var file = File.OpenRead("serialized.bin"))
            {
                var deserialized = Serializer.Deserialize<Outer>(file);
            }
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Inner
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Outer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public object Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. protobuf-net requires a positive integer *key* per member; this can be provided via `Order=` on `[DataMember]`. Low numbers are better, so typically this means `1`, `2`, `3`...
2. the protobuf specification is a schema-bound serializer; it wants to understand the data in advance; `object` does not work nicely.

but this would work:

```
[DataContract]
public class Inner
{
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Outer
{
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    public Inner Body { get; set; }
}
```

There *is* some support for flexibly typed data (i.e. `object`), but note that it is protobuf-net specific (it will not play nicely re portability). I would encourage you to look at the typed approach *first*. But it *can* do that: I'd just prefer it if you didn't ;p

If you **cannot** change the existing model, then the *first* thing I would advise would be: add a separate DTO model that looks a lot like your existing model, but marked for serialization, and work with that - and shim between the two models. If *that* isn't an option, you'll need to configure the system, to a: define keys for members, and b: tell it to use *dynamic*. For example:

```
var config = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
config.Add(typeof(Inner),false).Add("Id");
config.Add(typeof(Outer), false).AddField(1, "Body").DynamicType = true;
```

(note: `Serializer.*` is basically a short-cut to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`, so this configuration does talk to methods on `Serializer.*`)

Comment: 10x Marc. The RuntimeTypeModel works when body is of type object. What bothers me is that Inner can be any type. For example Outer is a wrapper around EventMessage and each EventMessage has different fields or properties. Do you suggest to use reflection for adding these event messages into the condif?

Comment: @mynkow no, I suggest using a simple DTO model that is designed for serialization :) a lot of serializers will choke on "object" - it is not an ideal usage. The only one that will prefer that is BinaryFormatter and NDCS. Which have their own problems :)

Answer (score 0):

for object property, you can use this:

[ProtoMember(1, DynamicType=true)]
public object Value { get; set; }

Comment: Proto attributes are different story